# '_cacheManager == null': is not true audio service issue fix

Tags: null, flutter-dependencies, audio-service, cachemanager

If anybody getting an issue in the audio_service library in flutter then this minor code may be helpful in fixing it

```
WillPopScope(
onWillPop: () async {
        await _audioHandler.stop();
        return true;
      },
child: Scaffold(...))
```

Comment: You've posted an answer as a question. Try instead to post a question as a question, then post an answer to your own question. But note, the `_cacheManager==null` assertion doesn't relate to `stop()`, it has to do with incorrectly calling `init` a second time.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because I initialized `just_audio_background` and `audio_service` package at the same time.

Comment: Also, I got the same error when executing AudioService.init twice