# Audio_service '_cacheManager == null': is not true after app restart

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

I need to restart application with audio_service. when user sign out app should clear cache and restart. after restart when trying to reinitialise audio service I've got an error:

```
flutter: 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart': Failed assertion: line 993 pos 12: '_cacheManager == null': is not true.
```

and AudioService can not be initialised thus.

After splash screen on the player screen we can start/pause audio and restart application. To restart app from player screen on button tap I am doing:

```
 FilledButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  BlocProvider.of<PlayerCubit>(context).clearCache();
                  RestartWidget.restartApp(context);
                },
                child: const Text('Restart App'),
              ),
```

Other code:

```
Future<void> runAudioApp() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  await _initServices();

  runApp(
    const RestartWidget(
      onRestart: _initServices,
      child: AudioApp(),
    ),
  );
}

Future<void> _initServices() async {
  print('RestartWidget _initServices()');
  await di.init();
}
```

where

```
class RestartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const RestartWidget({
    required this.onRestart,
    required this.child,
    super.key,
  });

  final Widget child;
  final void Function() onRestart;

  static void restartApp(BuildContext context) {
    context.findAncestorStateOfType<_RestartWidgetState>()?.restartApp();
  }

  @override
  State<RestartWidget> createState() => _RestartWidgetState();
}

class _RestartWidgetState extends State<RestartWidget> {
  Key key = UniqueKey();

  void restartApp() {
    setState(() {
      widget.onRestart.call();
      key = UniqueKey();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => KeyedSubtree(
        key: key,
        child: widget.child,
      );
}
```

injection_container contain:

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> init() async {
  await sl.reset();
  try {
    sl.registerSingleton(AppAudioCache());
    if (!sl.isRegistered<AppAudioHandler>()) {
      try {
        sl.registerSingleton<AppAudioHandler>(
          await initAudioService(audioCache: sl()),
        );
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  await sl.allReady();
}
```

Here is repo with a minimal reproduction [project](https://github.com/vladislove80/audio_restart): two screens splash and player.

I have seen this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71525340/cachemanager-null-is-not-true-audio-service-issue-fix).

and I have seen in the Audio Handler [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/audio_service/latest/audio_service/AudioService/init.html):

"Register the app's AudioHandler with configuration options. This must be called once during the app's initialisation ... "
so does it mean that it is impossible to initialise new instance of AudioService on application restart? maybe there is a way to completely destroy the audio service instance in order to create a new one? perhaps the restart itself was done incorrectly? thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to interpret the documentation is that app initialisation only happens once when the Flutter engine itself is created and it enters your `main` method for the first time. So merely creating a method called `restartApp` and calling it multiple times does not mean you can make app initialisation happen more than once. So you can't initialise audio_service more than once in the same launch of your app.

And since you are passing in exactly the same `init` parameters each time you're trying to call it, there is actually no need for you to initialise twice. If all you're trying to do is create an artificial method `restartApp` with some application logic in it, you can create such a custom method inside your existing audio handler instance and call it rather than re-initialising the whole system.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was waiting for it. looks like your advice is correct and suitable for my case: no need to initialise all instances in injection container one more time on application restart. good catch!